# flutter_svg: flag svg from restcountries.eu not loading

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I'm using the flag svgs of https://restcountries.eu/ and I'm having issues with a few from the total 251 flags.
This is how I display the flag:

```
SvgPicture.network(country.flagUrl,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Row(
    children: [
      const SizedBox(width: 7.5),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 30,
        width: 30,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          strokeWidth: 2,
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 7.5),
    ],
)),
```

[image]

As you can see the svg from American Samoa is not loading so it's displaying the progess indicator.
This is the url to the svg which is not getting loaded: https://restcountries.eu/data/asm.svg
This one for example is an svg that get's loaded: https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg
I suspect that there must be a difference between the two svgs and I read that [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) has some issues with css styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SVG contains "1pt" which is not supported in the library, you can try to download and replace that for 1px and it will work.

Maybe you could add them as assets and fixed them.

Comment: Thanks for your response how can I see if the svg contains "1pt" in the google developer tools?